# Diagonalisation of a quadratic Hamiltonian for bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian

As far as I know, every quadratic Hamiltonian can be diagonalised by a suitable basis change. Let me consider the basic squeezing Hamiltonian
$$
H = \gamma (a^2+{a^\dagger}^2)
$$
defined for the bosonic creation and annihilation operators $a$, $a^\dagger$.
If I follow the standard approach of the [Bogoliubov transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224283/second-quantization-and-hamiltonian-diagonalization), namely looking for a $b=u a + v a^\dagger$ such that $H=\omega b^\dagger b$, I obtain a system of equations containing $|u|^2+|v|^2=0$ which is meaningless.

(For details about the math you can look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/224301/160397 with $E+\Delta=0$.)

Where am I misunderstanding things?
If every quadratic Hamiltonian can be diagonalised, and the way to do it is a Bogoliubov transformation, what is the problem here?

EDIT: this question is not about the math, as the underlying calculation is straightforward. The question can be expressed as: what is wrong with the Bogoliubov transformation here? Why the transformation to diagonalise H is not of that form?

Comment: You have to give more information. What have you tried so far? Summarize your results.

Comment: There is no much to try: as far as I know the Bogoliubov transformation should lead to a diagonal H, but this seems not to be the case. So I'm asking what is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: What the... Perhaps you did a mistake?

Comment: No, you can look also here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/224301/160397 with $E+\Delta=0$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true for every Hamiltonian. The issue with yours is that it is not positive. The easiest way to see this is to think classically using $a=\frac{x+ip}{\sqrt 2}$:
$$
H=\gamma(x^2-p^2)
$$
(in the quantized version, you’d have an extra constant term). As you can see, the origin is not the minimum but rather a saddle point so you cannot use a change of variables to get $H$ of the form:
$$
H=\omega b^\dagger b
$$
See a similar issue in [Vacuum state of Bogoliubov quasi-particles (continued)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/767832/vacuum-state-of-bogoliubov-quasi-particles-continued). As explained there, your case $E+\Delta=0$ corresponds to the case where your Hamiltonian ceases to be positive definite.

Hope this helps.

**Answer to comment**

I’ve never mentioned diagonalisation. What I wrote is that you cannot use a Boguliubov transformation: $b=ua+va^\dagger$ to write the hamiltonian in the form: $H=\omega b^\dagger b$. This is because the latter is positive definite, while the former is not.

The closest analogue would be the change of variable:
$$
b=a+a^\dagger\\
\tilde b= a-a^\dagger
$$
so that: $H\propto \tilde b b$, though importantly $\tilde b\neq b^\dagger$.

Actually, the core of the discussion has little to do with quantum mechanics and has more to do with classical Hamiltonian mechanics.

Comment: I do not understand: only quadratic hamiltonians that are positive-definite can be diagonalised? I don't think that's the case, it is easy to find counterexamples like spin Hamiltonians with negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @m137:  I think it's more accurate to say that quadratic Hamiltonians that are not positive definite cannot be written in the form $H = b^\dagger b$ for some operator $b$.  An operator written in this form *must* be positive definite, since $\langle \psi | H \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | b^\dagger b \psi \rangle =  \langle b \psi | b \psi \rangle \geq 0$.